# Convert a string CSV to HTML table in PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, html-table

I am making a small financial market widget using PHP & HTML. I want to convert the following CSV string to a HTML table

```
result=1&size=200 EURUSD;1.11143;1.11143;1.11170;1.11025;1468549348 CADJPY;82.333;82.345;82.382;81.411;1468549348 EURGBP;0.81374;0.81386;0.83144;0.77313;1466801995 CADCHF;0.76110;0.76110;0.76120;0.75957;1468549347
```

I am getting the above value in a string called $result.

How can I display as a standard HTML table like:

**Symbol |  Bid   |  Ask  |  High  |  Low  |  Time**
EURUSD | 1.11143 | 1.11143 | 1.11170 | 1.11025 | 1468549348

and so on..

Edit:

Tried

```
$csvData = $result;
$lines = explode("\n", $csvData);
 echo "<table class='display' id='example'><thead >"; 
 echo "<tr class = 'even_gradeC'>
    <th class='history'><strong>Symbol</strong></th>
    <th class='history'><strong>Bid</strong></th>
    <th class='history'><strong>Ask</strong></th>
     <th class='history'><strong>High</strong></th>
    <th class='history'><strong>Low</strong></th>
    <th class='history'><strong>Time</strong></th>

    </tr>";
    echo "</thead>";    
 foreach ($lines as $line) 
{
$data = explode(';', $line );
if(count($data)==6) 
{
echo"<tr class='even_gradeC'>";
foreach($data as $row => $value)
{
if($row<>6)
//{
if ($row==1)
{
echo "<td align='right'>";
echo $value;
echo "</td>";

}
elseif ($row==2)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value;
echo "</td>";
}
elseif ($row==3)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value; 
echo "</td>";
}
elseif ($row==4)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value; 
echo "</td>";
}

elseif ($row==5)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value; 
echo "</td>";
}
elseif ($row==6)
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value; 
echo "</td>";

}
else
{
echo "<td>";
echo $value;
echo "</td>";
}
} 
echo "<td>";
echo $value;
echo "</td>"; 
} 
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Try something and get back to us. Stack overflow isn't here to do your work for you.

Comment: Split the strings by the space, then do an 'explode' using ; as the delimiter

Comment: Hint: [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

Comment: Already made the table. But the first colum shows result=1&size=0 EURUSD. How can I skip the first one?

Comment: result=1&size=0 EURUSD is the first part of the csv , so it is getting displayed as first column name .Please share the code what you have tried to debug easily

Comment: Posted my current PHP code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$csvLines = explode("\n", $csvData); // or use space as delimiter

echo "<table><tbody>";

foreach ($csvLines as $line) {
    $lineData = explode(";", $line);

    if (6 != count($lineData)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo "<tr>";

    foreach ($lineData as $value) {
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```